# My i5 laptop is running python script faster than Xeon 40 core server's cpu Ubuntu 18.04, Why?

Tags: python, linux, performance, x86, intel

I have created a python script which is reading data from a file and extracts required data from it, the problem is that script is taking 37 seconds on my i5 (Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz) laptop but it takes 70 seconds on server having CPU (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz).

Server's CPU has 40 cores so it should have performed task faster than my laptop. Both systems is running ubuntu 18.04 OS.

The script is using multiprocessing, and the server is my other system, it is not under higher load. My laptop has SSD and HHD both (os is installed in SSD) but I have put the file in HDD drive from which script is reading data and Server has only HDD. The file size is around 1 GB and I have tested the performance with 1000 records.

1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q2wv6saL3Q - testing a script on my 40 core server.

2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSInldq1uRY - testing the same script on her 8 core computer

The following code is running in for loop while reading data from 1GB file and target methods are using beautiful soup to extract data from doc which I am getting from the file.

```
t0 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_domain, args=(record.url, processedData))
t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getTLD, args=(record.url, processedData))
t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=geturlscheme, args=(record.url, processedData))
t3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getAllemails, args=(soup, processedData))
t4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getCanonicalURL, args=(soup, processedData))
t5 = multiprocessing.Process(target=getMetaKeyword, args=(soup, processedData))
t0.start()
t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
t5.start()
t0.join()
t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
t5.join()
```

Following are the details of cps of both systems by using lscpu command:

Laptop's details

```
:~$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               158
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            10
CPU MHz:             800.023
CPU max MHz:         4000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            4608.00
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
```

Server's detail

```
root@ubuntu18:~# lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              40
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-39
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  10
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               62
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             1200.470
CPU max MHz:         3300.0000
CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
BogoMIPS:            5000.02
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            25600K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-9,20-29
NUMA node1 CPU(s):   10-19,30-39
```

Please let me know what could be the reason for it, am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the code? If you use single-threaded code, you won't see any difference between machines with the same frequency. If you start 40 processes but all block waiting for each other, you won't see any difference

Comment: Any stats on the HDDs? Is it possible your machine's HD has a higher reading speed?

Comment: `The script is using multiprocessing` this can be tricky in python. Please provide the script source :)

Comment: Data parallelism works by partitioning the data into as many partitions as there are workers and having each one crunch its own partition independently. That's the best possible case. Any kind of synchronization means the workers have to stop and wait for sync to finish. Code that requires a lot of synchronization will end up running a *lot* slower in a many-core machine. Instead of 4-way syncs you have 40-way syncs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xeon E5-xxxx v2 is IvyBridge.  That's pretty old.  If your workload mostly bottlenecks on single-threaded performance, your results look very reasonable.  A modern quad-core has better per-thread memory bandwidth (but lower max aggregate with multiple threads), and also lower memory latency.  (Smaller ring bus between cores and memory controllers).

Max turbo for your laptop is also higher (4GHz vs. 3.3GHz).

Also, Haswell and newer have a branch predictor that's significantly better at running interpreters (like CPython); might want to profile for branch mispredicts to see if there's a big difference in that.

**It looks like you have a fixed number of threads**.  It's more than you have physical cores on the laptop, but it's plausible it scales well with hyperthreading (or a couple of the threads finish relatively quickly, so total runtime is mostly the time for the slowest thread running alone).  And plausible it doesn't bottleneck on shared memory bandwidth.

Then you're mostly worried about per-thread performance, and your laptop is faster per thread.

---

Re: 1GB file: hopefully that stays hot in the OS's disk cache.  (Aka "pagecache" under Unix/Linux).  So actual IO to disk doesn't happen, just reading RAM.

Comment: Can you please recommend me any processor that can give the best performance in term for processing?

Comment: @user1578460: no, it depends on your workload.  (Cache size vs. CPU frequency, and what levels of AVX512 matter.  Also # of cores, whether a huge many-core AMD would be good or whether you mostly need high single-threaded performance.)  Generally a high-clock-frequency Skylake-family quad or hex core, or Zen 2, will be pretty good for single-threaded throughput though.  (Many-core Intel CPUs have *lower* per-core memory bandwidth and worse memory latency.)

Answer (score 0):

I have identified two issues that slow down the server a lot.

1. The SSD. or the lack of a SSD, Really.  Python might be accessing its linked or reference files a lot.
2. The laptop hard drive is faster than it appears: it has a great active cache management that older drives don't have.  It still is a slow drive if it seeks for x data, but is fast if reading or writing a large chunk of a file, since it doesn't have to seek for the python linked and reference files, the cache isn't affected.

A cheap way to fix that would be to install a cheap ssd upgrade to the server and install the os, the compiler and the swap file on it. The latency of a hard drive for running a compiler isn't great in 2021.